# CLion Terminal Settings

Tags: terminal, clion

I'm using CLion to write a project, and the issue is that the stdout seems to automatically word wrap resulting in undesirable results. Example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1JSI.jpg

The newline wasn't put there by my program, so I'm just wondering if you can disable terminal word wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Clion 2017.1.1. It seems that there is a toggle called "soft wrap" that can disable word wrapping.

[Soft wrap off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYrfp.png)

[Soft wrap on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQPkC.png)